# Lighttpd python cgi broken on Xenial

Tags: server, python, lighttpd

I'm trying to setup Lighttpd web server with a very basic and SIMPLE cgi script. I don't need fastCGI or anything (i could use PHP, but ubuntu now forces you to use PHP7 which breaks every PHP5 script i have thanks for that PHP community!).

Anyways, i've wasted the last 2 days on this problem, which shouldn't be a problem at all, but for some reason recent versions of Ubuntu have broken things that used to always work.

Soooo..  Here's the problem.

Installed Lighttpd ... ok  works fine

Enabled the CGI module ... ok, good

in the config file  10-cgi.conf   changed:

```
cgi.assign      = (
#       ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
#       ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
#       ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python"
)
```

to:

```
cgi.assign      = (
#       ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
#       ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
       ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python"
)
```

Verified that   /usr/bin/python is actually there in that path....  ok..good.

created a cgi-bin directory ....ok

set permissions on the cgi-bin directory to be in the group and owned by:  www-data    ....ok

created a test python cgi file in the cgi-bin directory, and set it to executable and did a chmod 0755 test.py     .... ok...good. suceess

opened a web browser:   http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py   ...  BOOM

does it work, yes,  sort of.  It wants to download the web response as a file named  test.py.   It's not actually downloading the python file on the server, just the response the web server should be sending back to the browser.  I got this working before, and worked flawlessly.  But like i said, whatever the ubuntu distro devs are doing, it's breaking a lot of stuff that used to work. So online tutorials are patchy at best.

at first i thought maybe it was some MIME settings not quite right, so i manually added python MIME to the lighttpd.conf file.  Didn't seem to change anything.  i added the following to the bottom of the lighttpd.conf file:

```
mimetype.assign   += ( ".py" => "text/x-python" )
mimetype.assign   += ( ".pyo" => "application/x-python-code" )
mimetype.assign   += ( ".pyc" => "application/x-python-code" )
```

here's both of my config files:

10-cgi.conf:

```
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/cgi.txt
server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

## Warning this represents a security risk, as it allow to execute any file
## with a .pl/.php/.py even outside of /usr/lib/cgi-bin.
#
cgi.assign      = (
#       ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
#       ".php" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
       ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python"
)
```

lighttpd.conf:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
       "mod_rewrite",
#       "mod_cgi",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc",)
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi", ".cgi", ".py")

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

mimetype.assign   += ( ".py" => "text/x-python" )
mimetype.assign   += ( ".pyo" => "application/x-python-code" )
mimetype.assign   += ( ".pyc" => "application/x-python-code" )
```

am i just being absolutely retarded, or are the setup scripts that auto execute when ubuntu installs lightty get screwed up somewhere?

Comment: You write that your script works in older versions of Ubuntu. What about Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (with the trusty kernel) or Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (with the xenial kernel)? These versions are supported untill April 2019, so for more than two years from now. Maybe it is better to use one of those versions.

Comment: What does your `test.py` looks like?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on Ubuntu 18LTS. My test.py is `print "test"`